# UVW blurry in 3DMax

Tags: 3dsmax

I would like to get some help in 3DMAX. I have created a building and stucked with texturing. Iam very new with texturing though. So i setted up the uvw map printed into targa and also jpg 4096x4096 size and edited with photoshop. The picture is correctly fit to the object however it is so blurry cant even recognize the brick on the texture. I placed the texture on the uvw as well and it is nicely sharp but not on the object. I have watched and read many stuffs already but cannot find solution or just missed something. Any help would be appropriated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]For Direct3D driver (in Nitrous driver, as I know, there is no such problem):
Go to Customize-> Preferences...->Viewports->Configure Driver...
Select texture size as much as possible and check "Match Bitmap Size as Closely as Possible".
Click OK and restart Max.